# Trouble referencing API (React and Superagent)

Tags: reactjs, superagent

So by using postman I've managed to call the url for yummly. I'd like to render my search results. Currently in the render from lines 29 - 36 I have a fake search just to make sure the Dom works, and it does. How do I get the api search from lines 52 - 60 to show in 29 - 36.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Request from 'superagent';
import _ from 'lodash';


export class Yum extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {};
    }

    componentWillMount(){

        /*var url = "http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=5129dd16&_app_key=9772f1db10ba433223ad4e765dc2b537&=q"
        Request.get(url).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.body);
            this.setState({
                recipes: response.body.matches,
                total: response.body.totalResults           
            });
        });*/
        this.search();
    }

    updateSearch(){
        this.search(this.refs.query.value);
    }

    render(){
        

        const title = 'Onion Soup';
        const ingredients = ["onions", "beef stock"];
        const listItems = ingredients.map((ingredient) => {
          return (<h5>{ingredient}</h5>);
        });
        
        
        return(
            
            <div>
                <input ref="query" onChange = { (e) => {this.updateSearch();} } type="text" />
                
                <h4>{title}</h4>
                <ul>
                <li>{listItems}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }

    search(query = "onion") {
        var url = `http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=5129dd16&_app_key=9772f1db10ba433223ad4e765dc2b537&=q${query}&maxResult=1`
        Request.get(url).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.body.matches[0]);
            console.log(query);
            this.setState({
                recipes: response.body.matches[0],
                //total: response.body.totalResults
            });
        });
    }
}

export default Yum;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go I have cleaned up your code a bit, please give it a try

```
import React from 'react';
import Request from 'superagent';
import _ from 'lodash';

export class Yum extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            searchQuery: 'onion'
            recipe: {
                ingredients: []
            }
        };

        this.search = this.search.bind(this);
        this.queryUpdate = this.queryUpdate.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.search(this.state.searchQuery);
    }

    render(){
        const title = 'Onion Soup'; // Get this from somwhere else ?
        const {recipe, searchQuery} = this.state; // Get state properties

        const listItems = _.get(recipe, 'ingredients', []).map((ingredient) => {
            return (<h5>{ingredient}</h5>);
        });

        return(
            <div>
                <input onChange={this.queryUpdate} type="text" value={searchQuery} />

                <h4>{title}</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>{listItems}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }

    queryUpdate(e) {
        const searchQuery = event.target.value; // Get new value from DOM event
        this.setState({searchQuery}); // Save to state
        this.search(searchQuery); // Search
    }

    search(searchQuery) {
        const url = `http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=5129dd16&_app_key=9772f1db10ba433223ad4e765dc2b537&q=${searchQuery}&maxResult=1`
        Request.get(url).then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                recipe: response.body.matches[0]
            });
        });
    }
}

export default Yum;
```

Here are some of the issues I noticed:

- Typo in URL: =q instead of q=
- You should save the state of the text input in a state variable instead of using refs
- smaller details commented in code

Comment: Thank you, klugjo. This definitely worked after I made 'event' a property for queryUpdate.